# PHP wait for connection then print out once

Tags: php, connection, live

I am working on a chat application which should utilize PHP as some kind of server.
The client side is in Ajax, Javascript and it is able to send data using POST or read it from the server in JSON.
PHP Should listen for connection,and when chat message is sent by someone, it should print it out once to other clients which doesn't use same unique token. Then it stils wait for connection, etc.

I'm able to handle everything except PHP listening for connections and printing out when a new message is arrived.
So I will appreciate any help with that. Thanks!

EDIT: Everything works under SSL/HTTPS protocol.

Comment: Make a new AJAX request to a PHP file that just checks for new messages and let it pull every x seconds (3 to 5) via `setInterval`/`setTimeout`, that would be the most stable way I guess

Comment: I already done that in JS. Now I am trying to avoid writing text to file and/or database. Looking for some way to store it inside RAM.